# Issue in Creating a process builder as per a Task Due Date

Tags: workflow, date, tasks, process

Need your help urgently.  I tried several methods but failed.
I have to create two fields under the object " Lead". ( for insurance industry)
1.Renewal month (January, February… December etc)
2. To call at renewal (yes, no, blank)

In term of workflow, if 2 above is Yes to create a task “renewal follow-up” with a due date which falls on the 1st day of the month before expiry i.e. if the renewal month is December, the task due date should be 1st November . The year should be dependent on current month, if current month is > than expiry month, to set the year as current year + 1. So, if Renewal month is say, January, and now its September, then the due date year should be 2017- January.

Now I created two fields , both as picklist " Renewal month " i created as picklist with the month values ( but seems it shouldnt be picklist , as further in my rules its not taking as months ).
Then I created a process builder, criteria as if " to call at renewal = Yes", then
the below formula field on ths process builder,

**IF([Lead].Renewal_Month__c < MONTH(TODAY()),YEAR(TODAY()+1) ,  MONTH(TODAY()-1,1))**

But then as , its a picklist field its showing the error,

**Picklist are only supported only in certain function**

If i try to create this field as Date then i am getting all date/month/year, whereas i need only the month to get choose by the users. Can you plz suggest how to goahead with this, as i need to urgently implement this. Thanks

Comment: MONTH() returns an integer but Renewal_Month__c appears to be a string like `January` per your OP.  You will need to convert one or the other to be in coherence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Renewal_Month__c is the picklist where you are getting that error, you can use TEXT(Renewal_Month__c). In this way you will take the TEXT value of the picklist, in some functions you can't use picklist fields and you have to cast the value.